# Getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' when using list in the loop, which is declared outside loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, append, attributeerror

'When I run the below code, I get the following error. 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
Please help me out. I am new to Python'

> Blockquote

```
    x = list(map(int,raw_input("Enter a value: ").split()))
    x1=[]
    for i in range(0,len(x)):
        x1=x1.append(x[i])
    print(x1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.append(x)` modifies the list itself and returns *None*, so

```
        x1=x1.append(x[i])
```

assigns *None* to x1 and in the next iteration you encounter the error. Just write

```
        x1.append(x[i])
```

instead.